# How can everything be an object?

Tags: java, oop

In Java for example there is the primitive data type "int" which represents a 32 Bit value and there is "Integer" which is just a class with a single "int" property (and some methods of course). That means that a Java "Integer" class still uses primitives behind the scenes. And that's the reason Java is not a pure object oriented programming language.

Where could a value be stored if there where no primitives? For example I imagine this pseudo class:

```
class Integer
{
    private Integer i = 12;

    public Integer getInteger
    {
        return this.Integer;
    }
}
```

This would be recursive.

How can a programming language be implemented without primitives?

I appreciate any help solving my confusion.

Comment: It can't be *implemented* without primitives, but you don't need to make them apparent or accessible to the user of the language...

Comment: A programming language will at some point need to store an int to memory e.g. RAM. It's all bits and bytes and raw pointers under the hood of every language. Languages like Scala may decide to not expose primitives to the programmer

Comment: Documentation can make anything from nothing.

Comment: This question is too far removed from code for Stack Overflow.  It might be more appropriate on programmers.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'll rephrase the question to what I believe you're asking. If you think I've got it wrong, feel free to comment.)

> How can a type system that's based on composition and inheritance define any useful type, if there are no intrinsic types to start from? Unless the language implementation knows about at least one intrinsic type to start from, any defined types would be doomed to be either recursive or empty. Is this inevitable?

Yes, in every C-family language that I know of, this is pretty much inevitable.

If every type is composed of other types then, at the very least, you need to have an intrinsic type to build upon - for example, an intrinsic type that represents a *bit*, in order to construct the *byte* type out of it through composition, then the *word* type, then various *integer* types, and so on. Then you'd need to define the operations that can be performed on these types, by manipulating the bits that make up their internal representation.

And even though all you need is one intrinsic type to build upon, it would likely be terribly inefficient - you don't want to waste space or CPU cycles and you do want to take advantage of the various storage locations and instructions that your target architecture offers, including FP registers and other stuff.

Thus, a good compromise between performance and "purity" is to offer in the language some intrinsic types that are likely to be recognizable by modern CPUs (like *int32*, *int64*, *float*, *double*, etc) and build the rest of the type system upon them. In Java, they decided to call these intrinsic types *primitives* and make them separate from classes.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. Thank you! Also a big thank you to the others. You guys helped me out of my confusion.

Answer (score 11):

Behind the scene always will be primitives because it just a bits in memory. But some languages hide primitives that You can work only with objects. Java allows You to work both with objects and primitives.

Comment: I'm sure the OP gets it now.

Comment: So how? Processor can't work with objects.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean by `primitives` value types, then yes you can live without them as a user and use `Integer` instead of `int` and pay for the overhead of heap allocation and `GC`. But this doesn't come for free and you have to pay the cost. Primitives like 32-bit/64-bit integers and `IEEE-754 floating points` will always be faster because there is a hardware support for them.

From a compiler writer point of view you have to use what the machine supports to make things work.

Answer (score 3):

LISP is a very simple functional language. The basic LISP did not have a primitive `int` and one solution to integers was to have `successor of successor of successor of zero` for 3.

This actually had some advantages, integers being open ended, no overflow so operations really commutative, associative, and so on. Some nice optimizations possible. And of course `succ(succ(succ(zero)))` could be encoded in a more tuple like way (probably better not in LISP).

In a later, normal, LISP '3' would be an atom, 123 would be such an atom, with math operators.

Then there are symbol manipulating languages (SNOBOL) that could do math on numerical strings `['4', '0'] * ['3']`.

So names are objects (atoms) like a char 'a' or int 42.

Answer (score 3):

It might help to show you the analogous code in a language that takes the "everything is an object" design principle *much more seriously* than Java does.  Namely, [Smalltalk](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~harry/musings/SmalltalkOverview.html).   Imagine what it would be like if Java had only `int`, not `Integer`, *but* everything you used to need to use `Integer` for was possible with `int`.  That's Smalltalk.

This is an excerpt of the code defining the `SmallInteger` class in [Squeak 5.0](http://squeak.org/):

```smalltalk
Integer immediateSubclass: #SmallInteger
        instanceVariableNames: ''
        classVariableNames: ''
        poolDictionaries: ''
        category: 'Kernel-Numbers'!
!SmallInteger commentStamp: 'eem 11/20/2014 08:41' prior: 0!
My instances are at least 31-bit numbers, stored in twos complement
form. The allowable range in 32-bits is approximately +- 10^9
(+- 1billion).  In 64-bits my instances are 61-bit numbers,
stored in twos complement form. The allowable range is
approximately +- 10^18 (+- 1 quintillion).   The actual
values are computed at start-up.  See SmallInteger class startUp:,
minVal, maxVal.!

!SmallInteger methodsFor: 'arithmetic' stamp: 'di 2/1/1999 21:31'!
+ aNumber 
        "Primitive. Add the receiver to the argument and answer with the result
        if it is a SmallInteger. Fail if the argument or the result is not a
        SmallInteger.
        Essential, No Lookup. See Object documentation whatIsAPrimitive."

        <primitive: 1>
        ^ super + aNumber! !

!SmallInteger class methodsFor: 'instance creation' stamp: 'tk 4/20/1999 14:17'!
basicNew

        self error: 'SmallIntegers can only be created by performing arithmetic'! !
```

Don't sweat the fine details of syntax or semantics.  What you should get out of this is:  `SmallInteger` is defined as an object class just like everything else in the language, and arithmetic operations are methods just like every other piece of code in the language. But it's a little odd.  It has no instance variables, you can only create instances by performing arithmetic, and most of the methods look like they're being defined circularly.

"Under the hood", the implementation maps arithmetic to the appropriate  machine instructions (the `<primitive: 1>` thing is a hint to the implementation about that) and stores `SmallInteger`s as nothing more than the integer itself. The restricted range, relative to the hardware, is because a couple of bits are reserved to mark memory words as integers, rather than pointers to objects ("[tagged pointers](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-07-27-lets-build-tagged-pointers.html)").

Answer (score 2):

Without being able to eventually access real data, (eg. primitives or actual bits) (directly or indirectly) on a machine, it is no longer a programming language, it is an [Interface Description Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_description_language).

Answer (score 1):

Eventually everything comes back to bits in memory and instructions to the computer. The difference between assembler, compiled, procedural, object oriented, and all the other things is how much abstraction there is between you and the bits and how much benefit (or cost) you get from that abstraction.